# Updating .NET Runtime Enterprise Security Policy by Appending to File

Tags: .net, security, policy

We are updating our .NET 2.0 enterprise security policy (enterprisesec.config) across the company by running an .MSI package per workstation that will replace the existing config file with another one. Is there a way to add a code group to the existing policy instead of replacing the entire policy? We are worried about possibly removing an existing code group on some computers that may not be included in config file that will be pushed out globally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tooling available for this.  However, you could create an MSI or script that programmatically manipulates the contents of the policy file in order to add your new code group without touching anything else.  However, you should keep in mind that such an approach could still lead to problems if any given target file already has a code group of the same name as the one you wish to add.